# how to access, search and book meetings in Exchange 2007 via SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server-2007

Hejsan,

I need to search the Exchange 2007 for meetings booked during the specific times. For example, meetings booked from  3pm-4pm on January 21st,2011. How can achieve this, preferably using the SharePoint object model? Any code samples will be appreciated.

Comment: Karin: Maybe you could point to the question that answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2010/05/19/exchange-web-services-ews-managed-api-ndash-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the exchange web services for that.

Comment: You can't use Exchange web services since they are supported with .NET 3.5 Framework!